# Antlr: Reference to data not yet parsed

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am currently trying to implement an Antlr v4 grammar which takes text spreadsheets as input (Each 'cell' is separated by a tab). The grammar supports referencing to other cells, including references used in arithmetic expressions. Output is the same as input but all expressions are completed and each reference is replaced by the integer value of the cell that is referenced.

Example input:

```
1    9    5
     4    3    A3
     =A2+C3    6
```

and output:

```
1    9    5
     4    3    5
     15
```

I am unsure of how to implement the parser in my java application. Since cells could contain references to cells which have not been parsed yet, the grammar must finish parsing cells before evaluating expressions. From my understanding, the grammar visitor can return values DURING the parse, but will not be able to evaluate expressions containing references to cells not yet parsed.

What is the best way to approach this? The only solution I was able to determine would be to split the grammar into two smaller grammars, one which parses the cells and another which parses the expressions inside of the cells. However, I would rather keep it simple with only one parsing process.

In one sentence, **In Antlr4, what is the best way to handle a reference to data not yet parsed?**

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to evaluate the expression during the parse run. Do the entire process in 2 steps: first parse the input to get the parse tree and then use a visitor to evaluate it. After step one all cells are parsed into the parse tree and hence can be resolved in the evaluation step.

Comment: +1 IMHO it's always a good idea to do the evaluation using your own model. not the *Context objects generated by antlr.

Comment: I misread this answer the first time I looked at it. How exactly, in Antlr, would I implement the evaluation step? From my understanding, the visitor does a depth-first traversal. What I need is a breadth first for the cells, and then a depth first for the expressions inside the cells

Comment: If you need a different walk strategy then create your own visitor class. Everything in the AbstractParseTreeVisitor can be overridden. Implent your own variant of the `visitChildren()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it